# Cannot call own method on class extension where main class extends from FormTemplateControl

Tags: extension-methods, axapta, x++, dynamics-365

In D365, on my dialog form with a Dialog - Basic pattern, I'm using a Retail Matrix element (I've named it VariantMatrix):

[image]

This element uses the class RetailMatrix which extends from FormTemplateControl

[image]

I've extended the class and created my own method called test

[image]

I'm calling this method in my codebehind of the form:

[image]

but my form cannot compile and keeps return this error:

```
Error: ClassDoesNotContainMethod: Control 'VariantMatrix' does not contain a definition for method 'test' and no extension method 'test' accepting a first argument of type 'VariantMatrix' is found on any extension class.
```

Just to verify that my extended class works, I've created a chain of command method on .setDataCellValue(...) and it works:

[image]

Why does my compiler keeps complaining about my test method?

Comment: Have you tried recompiling everything?

Comment: Yes, I tried to recompiling everthing and even build every models available but didn't success